# Default record for Tab

Tags: visualforce, tab

I want to add a tab to my app that loads a record based on the currently logged in user. Is there a way to do that easily or am I going to have to develop the VF page using a custom controller and handcraft the entire thing? I have created and dummy VF page and used the URL to append a ?id= manually to test it but I want to have the page load the ur and populate the ID based on the current user.

The record I want to load is a custom object which has a lookup field to the user object so there is a field on the custom object that I can reference. Being relatively new to the VF world I'm not sure if there is a way to run code "before" the page is rendered except using a custom controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern should work.

You write a page that does nothing more than call a controller method (via the `action` attribute) and that method can return a different page that is displayed instead of his first page:

```
<apex:page controller="YourObjectController" action="{!redirect}">
    No record found for you.
</apex:page>
```

Then the controller just contains the logic to identify the right page:

```
public with sharing class YourObjectController {
    public PageReference redirect() {
        YourObject__c[] sobs = [
                select Id
                from YourObject__c
                where User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()
                order by CreatedDate desc
                limit 1
                ];
        if (sobs.size() == 1) {
            // Go to the default layout page for the right object ID
            return new PageReference('/' + sobs[0].Id);
        } else {
            // Stay on same page that has a hard-coded error message
            return null;
        }
   }
```

The user doesn't see the first page at all.

The [apex:page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) documentation explains the `action` attribute like this:

> The action method invoked when this page is requested by the server.
>   Use expression language to reference an action method. For example,
>   action="{!doAction}" references the doAction() method in the
>   controller. If an action is not specified, the page loads as usual. If
>   the action method returns null, the page simply refreshes. This method
>   will be called before the page is rendered and allows you to
>   optionally redirect the user to another page. This action should not
>   be used for initialization.

Comment: Excellent, I'll give it a try and let you know, thanks Keith.

Comment: Finally tried this eons later and got it working! Thanks Keith!